# Implementing a counter in a stack program to count how many times an object has moved

Tags: c++, arrays, input, stack, counter

all. I have learned about stacks and how they work and am working on an exercise to move cars into a parking lot via 2 stacks (2 lanes of the parking lot). My code needs some work but I am trying to implement some kind of counter that allows me to see how many times a car has been moved in the stack.

Here is my code right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

struct car
{
    char code;
    string license;
    int hour;
    int min;
    int num_moves;
};

class stack
{
  public:
   static const int CAPACITY = 10;
   typedef car STACK_TYPE;          ///MODIFIED from int to car
   stack();                 // constructor
   void push(STACK_TYPE);       // add element to the stack
   STACK_TYPE pop();            // return top element
   bool is_empty();             // is stack empty?
   bool is_full();

  private:
   int top;
   STACK_TYPE items[CAPACITY];
};
stack::stack()
{
 top=-1;//nothing on stack initially
}

void stack::push(STACK_TYPE value)
{
 assert(top !=CAPACITY-1);
 top++;
 items[top]=value;
}

stack::STACK_TYPE stack::pop()
{
  STACK_TYPE value;
  assert(top>=0);
  value= items[top];
  top--;
  return(value);

}
bool stack::is_empty()
{
    if (top== -1) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool stack::is_full()
{
    if (top==CAPACITY-1) return true;
    else return false;
}

void arriving(string &a, int &b, int &c) //prints arriving car's license & time
{
  cout<<"car has been parked in the garage."<<endl;
  cout<<"license plate number: "<<a <<endl;
  cout<<"current time:" << b<<":";
  if (c>=10) cout<<c<<endl;
  else cout<<"0"<<c<<endl;
  cout <<"*********************"<<endl;

}


void departing(string &a, int&b, int &c)//prints departing car's license & time
{

  //cout << "Another car must be moved out of the way!";
  cout<<"License: "<<a<<endl;
  cout<<"Time of departure: " <<b<<":";
  if (c>=10) cout<<c<<endl;
  else cout<<"0"<<c<<endl;
}

void time_parked(int &a, int &b, int &c, int &d)//prints time parked
{
 int hour_diff;
 int min_diff;
 if (d<b)//if departing minutes is less than arriving minutes
 {
   c--;
 }
 hour_diff = c-a;
 min_diff = d-b;
 cout<<"Time Parked: "<<hour_diff<<":";
 if (min_diff>=10) cout<<min_diff<<endl;
 else cout<<"0"<<min_diff<<endl;
}

void print_garage();

stack garage;
stack garage2;
stack street;       ///GLOBAL

int main ()
{
//  stack garage;
//  stack street;
  car cars[100];
  car temp;
  int new_hour;
  int new_min;
  int x=0;

  fstream textfile;
  textfile.open("lab4.txt");


 while(!textfile.eof())
 {
  textfile>>cars[x].code; 
  textfile>> cars[x].license;

  if (cars[x].code =='A')   
  {
     if (garage.is_full())
     {
     cout<<"Garage is full."<<endl;
     cout<<"License: "<<cars[x].license<<endl; 
     cout<<"Moving future cars to garage2!";
      if (garage2.is_full())
      {
        cout<<"Garage is full."<<endl;
        cout<<"License: "<<cars[x].license<<endl;
      }
      else{
        textfile>>cars[x].hour;
       textfile>>cars[x].min;
       arriving(cars[x].license, cars[x].hour, cars[x].min);
       garage2.push(cars[x]);
      }
     }
     else
     {
       textfile>>cars[x].hour;
       textfile>>cars[x].min;
       arriving(cars[x].license, cars[x].hour, cars[x].min);
       garage.push(cars[x]);
     }
  }
  if (cars[x].code=='D')    
  {
    textfile>>new_hour;
    textfile>>new_min;
    while (!garage.is_empty())
    {
     temp = garage.pop();
     street.push(temp);
     while (temp.license!=cars[x].license)
     {//backing cars from garage to street until finding the matching license car
      if(!garage.is_empty())
      {
       temp = garage.pop();
       street.push(temp);
      }
     }
     if (temp.license!=cars[x].license)
     {
     cout<<"Car not found"<<endl;
     cout<<"License: "<<cars[x].license;
     }
     else
     {
     departing(cars[x].license, new_hour, new_min);
     time_parked(cars[x].hour, cars[x].min, new_hour, new_min);
     street.pop();
     }
    }
    while(!street.is_empty())
    {
     temp = street.pop();
     garage.push(temp);
    }
    print_garage();
  }
 }
}


void print_garage()
{
     car temp;
     while (!garage.is_empty())
     {
     temp = garage.pop();
     cout<<temp.license<<endl;
     street.push(temp);
     }
     while(!street.is_empty())
     {
     temp = street.pop();
     garage.push(temp);
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok. so what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you just need to increment `num_moves` of your cars in `stack::push`, although I'd suggest a member function in `car`:

```
void car::parkIn(const stack &garage)
{
    ++num_moves;
    garage.push(*this);
}
```